# Slowness on NSTableView with many images loaded thought web

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

There is a "View Based" NSTableView, text input "URL" to enter image URL and "Add button". Coded in Objective-C

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    return [self.items count];
}

- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    Item *item = [self.items objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *identifier = [tableColumn identifier];

    NSView *result = nil;

    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"thumb"]) {
        NSImageView *thisCell = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:identifier owner:self];
        NSString *url = [item valueForKey:@"url"];
        NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
        [thisCell setImage:image];
        result = thisCell;
    } else {
        NSString *value = [item valueForKey:identifier];
        NSTableCellView *thisCell = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:identifier owner:self];
        thisCell.textField.stringValue = value;
        result = thisCell;
    }

    return result;
}

-(IBAction)add:(id)sender {
    Item *testItem = [[Item alloc] init];
    testItem.title = @"Some Title";
    testItem.url = @"http://filmdash.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/sayhello_logo_300dpi_rgb.jpg";
    [self.items addObject:testItem];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Everything works fine, you fill URL, press add button, new row with URL and image preview columns is added to the table view loaded.

Image is being loaded synchronously from provided URL.

The problem happens when a lot of rows are added to the table view and you add each next record. Every time the table view is refreshed it loads all images from their URLs again.

Is there a standard way to avoid loading all images again on each table view refresh?

Or even better avoid loading all images again on each table view refresh and load them asynchronously the first time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

The easier version is to just reload the new index of the tableView instead of calling `reloadData`. By doing this, the other cells remain untouched.

The other solution is slightly more complex, but better. Create a images dictionary. Use something unique as the key. I think your `item.identifier` might work. Once you have downloaded a image, save it to the dict with the key. When the cell reloads, check if the image is available, otherwise download it.
I see several advantages here:

1. You have a nice dictionary that is ready to be saved (`NSKeyedArchiver`) for later use.
2. No re-download needed - not only `reloadData` loads cellViews. If a cell got off screen, it gets unloaded and reloads when getting visible. That way you get smooth scrolling again.

*Off topic:*
*I think that `NSURLConnection` would work better that `dataWithContentsOfURL:` because it works asynchronous and does not freeze the UI.. Photos might load instantly on your machine, but people with a slow internet connection will get a bad user experience because they can't use your app for several seconds. You can also add a `NSProgressIndicator` to indicate that the image is loading*

Comment: Progress bar is a good idea as well as NSURLConnection. I created NSURLConnectionDataDelegate to get image data and tracking progress inside, but how to set progress value / final image from inside the connection delegate to a particular table view cell? Sorry for such question, googled the answer but without success yet...

Comment: Just not sure how to get access to NSImageView *thisCell that is part of table view from inside the connection delegate that is a separate class.

Comment: Added another answer to show you how to load the images.

Answer (score 1):

This is a separate answer for the question that occurred in my first answer. So this is about loading images with `NSURLSession`.

You don't need the delegate methods. I tried it now and this works great: Do the usual setup: Add the progressIndicator to your tableCell and connect it to your custom tableCell class, so that you can access it in your code. Set the NSProgressIndicator style to spinning and to intermediate. Don't forget to uncheck "Display when stopped".

You can load the image right in your `- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row;` delegate method. The code looks something like this:

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    if ([tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"MainCell"]) {
        TableCellView* tableCell = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"cellID" owner:self];

        //Set up session
        NSURLSession* session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
        NSURLSessionDownloadTask* task = [session downloadTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR URL"] completionHandler:^(NSURL * _Nullable location, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (!location) { ** error ** } else {
                NSData* downloadData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:location];
                NSImage* image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:downloadData];
                //Check if actual image was created..
                tableCell.imageView.image = image;

                //Stop the spinner
                [tableCell.progressIndicator stopAnimation:nil];
                }    
            }];

            //Start the spinner
            [tableCell.progressIndicator startAnimation:nil];

            //Start the task
            [task resume];

            //Other cell setup
            [tableCell.textField setStringValue: "Foo Bar"];
            return tableCell;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

The result looks something like this..
[image]

Comment: Great, thanks a log Max. I also posted an alternative solution without using blocks. I'm not sure yet which one is more optimal.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to a good Max's answer about tracking the progress, figured out how to track progress of downloading with NSURLConnectionDataDelegate. Initializing connection delegate for each column and setting cell on each instance of connection delegate, then when connection delegate does it job it has access to the cell to update components there.

TableViewDelegate.m

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    Item *item = [self.items objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *identifier = [tableColumn identifier];

    NSView *result = nil;

    if ([identifier isEqualToString:@"thumb"]) {
        NSImageView *thisCell = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:identifier owner:self];
        NSURL *urlReal = [NSURL URLWithString:item.url];

        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlReal];

        ThumbWithProgressDelegate *thumbConnectionDelegate = [[ThumbWithProgressDelegate alloc]init];
        thumbConnectionDelegate.thisCell = thisCell;  // set cell in delegate

        NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:thumbConnectionDelegate];
        result = thisCell;
    } else {
        NSString *value = [item valueForKey:identifier];
        NSTableCellView *thisCell = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:identifier owner:self];
        thisCell.textField.stringValue = value;
        result = thisCell;
    }

    return result;
}
```

ThumbWithProgressDelegate.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

@interface ThumbWithProgressDelegate : NSObject<NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableData *imageData;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger totalBytes;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger receivedBytes;

@property (nonatomic) NSImage *image;
@property (weak,nonatomic) NSImageView *thisCell;

@end
```

ThumbWithProgressDelegate.h

```
#import "ThumbWithProgressDelegate.h"

@implementation ThumbWithProgressDelegate

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
    NSDictionary *dict = httpResponse.allHeaderFields;
    NSString *lengthString = [dict valueForKey:@"Content-Length"];
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    NSNumber *length = [formatter numberFromString:lengthString];
    self.totalBytes = length.unsignedIntegerValue;

    self.imageData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:self.totalBytes];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [self.imageData appendData:data];
    self.receivedBytes += data.length;

    // Actual progress is self.receivedBytes / self.totalBytes
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:self.imageData];
    [self.thisCell setImage:image];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    //handle error
}

@end
```